# Integrating Twitter Bootstrap navbar with XenForo

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap for a site that uses XenForo for it's forums. I'd like to keep Bootstrap's navbar even when on XenForo, but the code for it is so strewn throughout the bootstrap.css file that I can't seem to carry over just those parts. Naturally, moving the entire bootstrap.css file screws up XenForo. Is there anyway this can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this tool to only include the css for the navigation bar:

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/download.html

Answer (score 0):

Even if you generate navbar-only code with the Bootstrap generator, it's still going to mess with XenForo's styling.

If you really want to take upon this project, you will have to at the minimum rename individual CSS elements to resolve all conflicts.

It's quite a bit of work, the amount of which is also going to depend on which XenForo style you're using.